# ¿Cómo hacer que input y textarea se auto ajusten al ancho de la tabla en donde se encuentran?

Tags: html, css3

Estoy haciendo un formulario en el he diseñado 2 columnas, una para labels que contendrán la descripción y la faltante para los input y textarea.

He especificado el ancho de la 1a columna con unos 84 pixeles y me gustaría que la segunda columna se auto-ajuste al ancho que tenga la tabla sin importar el ancho de la ventana del buscador.
A continuación la imágen de la estructura que tiene la tabla para el formulario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto he puesto en el css que es para la tabla o contenedor del formulario:

```
.formContacto{
     margin: auto;
     padding: 20px;      
     display: block;
  }
```

este estilo es para la 1a columna (donde van a ubicarse las descripciones)

```
.formContacto .descripcion{
      width: 84px;
      padding-top: 5px;
      display: flex;
      font-size: 0.7500em;
   }
```

para la columna faltante  pensaba utilizar la función calc() de esta forma:

```
.formContacto .casillero{
      width: calc(100% - 84px);
   }
```

y para el input y textarea no tengo la más remota idea de que estilos debo darles par que puedan cumplir el objetivo; **qué me recomiendan hacer?** ya que yo pensaba en darles un ancho heredado pero creo que no funcionaría.

Answer (score 0):

una opción para esto es:

```
.formContacto .casillero{
      width: 100%;
   }
   .form-contacto-input, .form-contacto-txtarea{
      width: inherit;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
   }
   .casillero input, .casillero textarea{
      border: none;
      border-radius: 2px;
      padding: 6px;
      width: inherit;
   }
```

De seguro hay otras soluciones  pero hasta al momento estoy utilizando esta.